# How to make my form fit the whole row on phone screen, but stay in middle on the desktop screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I struggling trying to make my form to take the whole row in phone screen/iPad screen, but start in the middle on a desktop screen. How should I configure my bootstrap class ?

I've tried

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4-offset-4">
//My Form
</div>
```

---

**Result**

`Phone` size look good

[image]

---

`Desktop` size look awful

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your code. It should go like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
   //My Form
</div>
```

Or you can just write this and it will do the same thing

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
   //My Form
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `col-lg-4-offset-4`

you need to use

`col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4`

(i.e. one class for the container width, another one for the offset)